# pg_prove run test case and output junit xml style result

Tags: pgtap

What is the command to let the pg_prove run test case and output the result to Junit xml style?

```
pg_prove -U ubuntu -d $DB database/test/all_database_tests.sql
```

Can we use --formatter `TAP::Formatter::JUnit` or --harness  `TAP::Harness::JUnit` to format the output?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `TAP::Harness::JUnit` to format the test result.

```
JUNIT_OUTPUT_FILE=/tmp/circleci-test-results/all_database_tests_results.xml pg_prove -U ubuntu -d $DB database/test/all_database_tests.sql --verbose --harness TAP::Harness::JUnit
```

`JUNIT_OUTPUT_FILE` tell pg_prove where the test result file name and path;
`--harness TAP::Harness::JUnit` tell pg_prove which format of result to output.

Before you install [`TAP::Harness::JUnit`](https://github.com/jlavallee/tap-harness-junit), you might need to install [`XML::Simple`](https://www.mclean.net.nz/cpan/) by command `sudo cpan XML::Simple` and [`Test::Deep`](https://github.com/rjbs/Test-Deep).

the full example is below:

```
git clone https://github.com/jlavallee/tap-harness-junit.git
git clone https://github.com/rjbs/Test-Deep.git

sudo cpan TAP::Parser::SourceHandler::pgTAP   # Install pg_prove
psql -U ubuntu -d $DB -c "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgtap;" #Create pgtap extension;
sudo cpan XML::Simple  #Install XML::Simple
cd Test-Deep && perl Makefile.PL && sudo make && sudo make test && sudo make install
cd tap-harness-junit && perl Build.PL && sudo ./Build && sudo ./Build install
JUNIT_OUTPUT_FILE=/tmp/circleci-test-results/all_database_tests_results.xml pg_prove -U ubuntu -d $DB database/test/all_database_tests.sql --verbose --harness TAP::Harness::JUnit
```